# Finish loading all components before displaying the page - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my current scenario, My homepage compose of multiple components with an HTTP request. Is it possible to display the page if only when all of my components finish their HTTP request?

Thanks!

P.S. I have no codes to show yet since im just in my planning stage on how will I developed the web app.

Comment: I usually have a div that takes up the whole viewport as a loading screen. It has absolute positioning, and has a higher z-index than the rest of the page. When the http calls are finished, you can hide the div with the final callback

Comment: But my problem is how can I detect if all(multiple) http calls are finished. I can do this if the page has only one http call but in my case since my homepage are breakdown into multiple component with http calls in each component. I can't think of ways on how to do it.

Comment: You could use the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) . Basically, you have one object that is being notified each time the http response is finished. Once it has been notified enough times (based on a list or simple count), it can reveal the page

Comment: Some the new frameworks like angular 2 or aurelia have that pattern built in ready to go.

Comment: I'd challenge you to consider whether this is a good idea. I think a better user experience is to load the page right away with some loading indicator (spinner, etc) or dummy content (think modern facebook posts)

Comment: @azium yeah I guess the dummy content with loader will be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your app is not coded yet, you can adopt better component structure.
These are approaches that i have seen or implemented.

**1. No global Loader needed in the first place -**

If each of your components can handle rendering even before data loaded, like use of a App Shell architechture as shown below.
a loading shell of a facebook post would look like
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBbTY.gif
Code

```
    class Post extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return !this.props.isLoading ? (
          <div className="post">...</div>
        ) : (
          <div className="post-shell"></div>
        ); 
      }
    }
```

**2. Global loader**

Code

```
    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return !this.props.isLoading ? (
          <RootComponent {...props}>
        ) : (
          <Loader />
        );
      }
    }
```

where Loader component is an absolutely positioned loading icon/content.
RootComponent is only mounted when data is loaded so that all props are having required data.

many projects don't have the luxury to the former as the components are not written with corresponding shells. but since you are not constrained by time. The first approach gives the best UX.

Comment: I guess I should go with number 1. Thanks for answering!

Comment: How to check `this.props.isLoading` condition ? @Sagi_Avinash_Varma

Comment: For option 2, I would even go with 'this.props.isLoaded', but thanks, you brought me on the right way.